# Get JSON object in Swift from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, nsdictionary

I have the following Dictionary:

```
let patientDictionary : [String: AnyObject] = ["name" : patientName, "email" : email, "mobileNumber" : mobileNumber]
```

And I get the following:

**3 elements:**

[0] : 2 elements
    .0 : "name"
    .1 : TestUser

[1] : 2 elements
    .0 : "email"
    .1 : testUser@test.test

[2] : 2 elements
    .0 : "mobileNumber"
    .1 : 9865784532

And, **String(patientDictionary)** gives me following:

```
"[\"name\": TestUser, \"email\": testUser@test.test, \"mobileNumber\": 9865784532]"
```

**How can I convert this to Swift JSON object?**

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(patientDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
let strJson = NSString(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

print(strJson)
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON Encoding**

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

**JSON Decoding**

```
do {
    let decoded = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? [String:String]
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Will keep in mind.